# First date when certain condition was met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a first date when a condition was met.  So the logic is below:

```
use
[AdventureWorksDW2012]
go

;WITH sales AS (

select      d.OrderDateKey,
        SalesAmount = SUM(d.SalesAmount)
from        [dbo].[FactInternetSales] d
group by    d.OrderDateKey
having      SUM(d.SalesAmount)>10000
) 

select  FirstOrderDateKey = MIN(OrderDateKey) 

from sales
```

The only problem is that in my data is too complex and too huge to calculate value for each date and then choose the min date when the condition is met. Is there any quick way of finding first date when Internet sales amount exceeded 10000? Is there some kind of loop required?

Comment: Are you sure it is "too complex and too huge"? That should run very quickly regardless of the amount of data you have. Make sure your tables have indexes.

Comment: Typically the thought of loops in the context of SQL is misplaced.  Think in terms of sets instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in single statement also. The performance can be improved with this if you have proper index on orderdatekey.

```
select      MIN(s.OrderDateKey) as FirstOrderDateKey
from        [dbo].[FactInternetSales] d
group by    d.OrderDateKey
having      SUM(d.SalesAmount)>10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
        d.OrderDateKey
       ,S.RunningTotal
FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] d
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) AS RunningTotal
                          FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
                          WHERE OrderDateKey <= d.OrderDateKey
                         ) S
WHERE S.RunningTotal <  -- Condition
ORDER BY d.OrderDateKey DESC
```

Comment: That is actually what i am looking for to be honest... as it looks at running total. Im just wondering if there is a better way, i.e. way of getting better performance ? (maybe something instead of CROSS APPLY?)

Comment: Changing it to CTE makes it 4secs quicker, but still not sure if that's the best approach? What about dynamic SQL?